# Difference between `polyfit` (Matlab) and `lm` (R) for linear fitting

Tags: r, matlab, data-fitting

I am looking to fit a line to the following data: `x`

```
1 2 3 4
```

and `y`

```
0.0000000 0.5376671 2.3715522 0.1127053
```

Starting from a code in Matlab:

```
coef = polyfit(x,y,1);
best = coef(1)*x+coef(2);
```

I developed the following code in R:

```
lmResult = lm(y ~ poly(x, 1))
intercept = coef(lmResult)["(Intercept)"]
slope = coef(lmResult)["poly(x, 1)"]
names(intercept) <- NULL
names(slope) <- NULL
best = slope*x+rep(intercept, length(x))
```

Unfortunately I obtained two different results for the array `best`:

```
1.241155 1.726829 2.212504 2.698178
```

for R,

```
0.4297
0.6469
0.8641
1.0813
```

for Matlab... and I can't explain it!

Comment: In R, `poly` creates orthogonal polynomials by default. Use `poly(x, 1, raw = TRUE)`. Also, prediction can be rewritten to `cbind(1, poly(x, 1, raw = TRUE)) %*% coef(lmResult)`.